# Glut deprecation in Mac OSX 10.9, IDE: QT Creator

Tags: c++, opengl, osx-mavericks, glut, deprecation-warning

I was trying to build an opengl program on qt creator, installed on my mac, with osx 10.9. 
I got several warnings on glut functions about its deprecation in osx10.9, a sample error message is like:

'glutInit' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    glutInit(&argc, &argv);
    ^

I wonder if GLUT.h is not usable anymore in osx10.9? According to some other posts, it is said that as long as we change "OS X Deployment Target" back to OSX10.8, then it works. How to do so in qtcreator? Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for a glut replacement (which I hope you'll be soon) there's GLFW (my fav), SDL or freeglut.

Comment: Thanks! What's the main difference between GLFW and GLUT?

Comment: Also, just an open question, does anyone has any idea why osx10.9 does not support glut anymore? Is it not a good library?

Comment: @HPH Pretty much, glut is pretty old and limited.

Answer (score 10):

You can still use it in 10.9. They're sending you a pretty strong signal that they want you to stop, though...

You can disable those warnings with the `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` compiler option.

There's also some difficulties including the right headers if you're trying to use GL3 level features, because you need to include `gl3.h` for that, while `glut.h` includes `gl.h`, which causes additional complaints about possible conflicts while building. The somewhat hacky workaround I found for this is to prevent `glut.h` from including `gl.h` by defining the header guard:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#define __gl_h_
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Then, for using GL3+ level features, you need to specify that with an additional flag to `glutInitDisplayMode()`:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(... | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
```

It looks like it's probably time to start using GLFW. I never used GLUT for anything serious, but it was always very convenient for small demos/tests.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: It's there in the standard GLUT that ships with Xcode. Just go check if you don't believe it. It's on line 186 of `glut.h` in both the `MacOSX10.8.sdk` and `MacOSX10.9.sdk` that ships with Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry. I did look but the OS X machine I have in front of me right now runs 10.6, so it is not surprising that constant does not exist now that I think about it :P I was mixing up that constant with `glutInitContextVersion (...)` (FreeGLUT's solution).