# Mac OS X refuses to create my OpenGL Window

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

void GraphiqueAffichage() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 272);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Bonjour");
    glutDisplayFunc(GraphiqueAffichage);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Hello
I am on a Mac using OS X 10.12, ans with this code, no window is displayed, is it normal ? Why ? Please help me.
The compilation is correct, no error, build successful, but no window is created !
I tried this code that works with windows but I have a Mac and it does not work, how to make it working ?

Answer (score 3):

> The compilation is correct, no error, build successful ...

but you get a list of errors when you *run* the program, right? "Successfully compiling" does not (alas) mean your *code* is correct.

Looking up the very first error message, it seems you forgot to call `glutInit` first:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    ...
```

(right where your code says, "insert code here"...)

`man glutInit` tells you why it failed as well:

> `glutInit` will initialize the GLUT library and negotiate a session with  the  window  system.

where "the window system" is Mac OS X.

In addition, your `main` is wrong. `argv` is not a `const char *` – with that `const` specifier, your compiler will yell at you.

With these changes, I get a nice yellow window – your `glClearColor` – and with the custom title "Bonjour".

Comment: yes, but it was not written in the book I bought, is it normal ?

Comment: A note on http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutinit says this: "You really should always call this, even if you are a WIN32 user." The author of your book may not have been aware of this. Some toolchains may complain [`glutInit` is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24095931/2564301); I guess that mainly depends on what version you are using. FWIW: your code, with changes, does not issue that specific warning on my system – Mac OS X 10.7.5, using `clang`.

Comment: @johnathanMhehdi: I guess the question is, does your program work with this? If not, I'll have to look further into this. You may need to add what book your code came from.

Answer (score 1):

You need initializer glut

> glutInit(&argc, argv);

in your main.

```
//#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

void GraphiqueAffichage() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 272);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Bonjour");
    glutDisplayFunc(GraphiqueAffichage);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```